# Random geometric shape's array task on java

Tags: java

I'm java newbie, currently working on this internship task:

*Given the figure objects of the following types: square, triangle, circle, trapezium. Each shape can be drawn, get its area and color. Also, the figures have unique methods, for example: return the radius, the length of the hypotenuse, the length of the side, etc.
We need to generate a random set of shapes, the number of objects in the set is also not known in advance.
After generating the array, you need to display the entire list of objects that we have, for example:*

Drawing triangle, area: 8.56, hypotenuse: 6.20, color: red

Drawing square, area: 27.27, side length: 5.22, color: blue

... and so on. **It is necessary to describe the task using the principles of OOP.**

What I need is general advices to make my code cleaner and better, and also some help with random array part. Here is the code I currently wrote:

**Shape interface:**

```
public interface Shape {
    void draw();

    double getArea();

    ColorEnum getColor();
}
```

**ColorEnum enum class:**

```
public enum ColorEnum {
    RED,
    ORANGE,
    YELLOW,
    GREEN,
    BLUE,
    INDIGO,
    VIOLET
}
```

**Square class:**

```
    import java.awt.*;

public class Square implements Shape {
    private double side;
    private Color color;

    public Square(Color color, double side) {
        this.color = color;
        this.side = side;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw() {
        System.out.println("Drawing square, area: " + String.format("%.2f", getArea()) + ", side length: " + String.format("%.2f", getSide()) + ", color: " + getColor());
    }

    @Override
    public double getArea() {
        return side * side;
    }

    @Override
    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public double getSide() {
        return side;
    }
}
```

**Triangle class:**

```
public class Triangle implements Shape {
    private double side1, side2, side3;
    private ColorEnum color;

    public Triangle(ColorEnum color, double side1, double side2, double side3) {
        this.color = color;
        this.side1 = side1;
        this.side2 = side2;
        this.side3 = side3;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw() {
        System.out.println("Drawing triangle, area: " + String.format("%.2f", getArea()) + ", hypotenuse: " + String.format("%.2f", getHypotenuse()) + ", color: " + getColor().name().toLowerCase());
    }

    @Override
    public double getArea() {
        double p = (side1 + side2 + side3) / 2;
        double s = Math.sqrt((p * (p - side1) * (p - side2) * (p - side3)));
        return s;
    }

    @Override
    public ColorEnum getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public double getHypotenuse() {
        double hypotenuse = 0;
        double[] arr = {side1, side2, side3};

        for (double i : arr) {
            if (hypotenuse < i) hypotenuse = i;
        }
        return hypotenuse;
    }
}
```

**Circle class:**

```
public class Circle implements Shape {
    private double radius;
    private ColorEnum color;

    public Circle(ColorEnum color, double radius) {
        this.color = color;
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw() {
        System.out.println("Drawing circle, area: " + String.format("%.2f", getArea()) + ", radius: " + String.format("%.2f", getRadius()) + ", color: " + getColor().name().toLowerCase());
    }

    @Override
    public double getArea() {
        return Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 2);
    }

    @Override
    public ColorEnum getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public double getRadius() {
        return radius;
    }
}
```

**Trapeze class:**

```
public class Trapeze implements Shape {
    private double base1, base2, height;
    private ColorEnum color;

    public Trapeze(ColorEnum color, double base1, double base2, double height) {
        this.color = color;
        this.base1 = base1;
        this.base2 = base2;
        this.height = height;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw() {
        System.out.println("Drawing trapeze, area: " + String.format("%.2f", getArea()) + ", height: " + String.format("%.2f", getHeight()) + ", color: " + getColor().name().toLowerCase());
    }

    @Override
    public double getArea() {
        return (base1 + base2) / 2 * height;
    }

    @Override
    public ColorEnum getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public double getHeight() {
        return height;
    }
}
```

Now back to random array part. I need random amount of shape's with random parameters. How to nicely implement stuff like this ? Should I use factory pattern ? I accidentally found one implementation on GitHub, can you tell me is it good ? 
https://github.com/Ligren/QaTestLab/blob/master/QaTestLab/src/Test/ShapeDrawing.java and https://github.com/Ligren/QaTestLab/blob/master/QaTestLab/src/Test/Start.java

Comment: be more specific on your question. as for the random, you can use `math.random` to generate random numbers in a radius of your choise and use the generated numbers to the inputs you need.

Comment: Sir. Hedgehog, the part is pretty simple, for example I can create array with random length, then fill it with random shape's using switch-case, also use switch-case for shape parameters, but I just want it to be good in terms of OOP, because this is very important require from a task I believe.

Comment: just try it with the `random` and see if it works. if something works you dont touch it :p apart from kidding though, just try it and if in the end you dont like what you see, then you can repost. as far as i understood, your problem was how to do the randomisers. which the math.random is ought to do it.

Comment: **1.** There is no need to define a color class. Better use a standard [color class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html). **2.** To make is simple and uniform you can have the same constructor to all shapes and let the shape be defined by the number of points: Cicle is defined by 2 points, triangle by 3, trapezium by 4. Note that a square is a subclass of trapezium. **3.** You'll need to override `toString` of each shape to output the required description like "triangle, area: 8.56, hypotenuse: 6.20, color: red".   (btw: `Circle` class is posted twice).

Comment: btw: Circle class is posted twice - just a copy-paste typo, fixed. So I need to insert line from draw () method in toString () ? Then draw () method will be useless ? Or it should contain smth like this.toString ?

Comment: And how can I simply display color using Color class ? I see that random colors creates like this - new Color(Start.rand.nextInt(256), Start.rand.nextInt(256), Start.rand.nextInt(256)), so how to "convert" this color to simply "red", "black" etc ?

Comment: Well, nevermind, I think it will be nice to use array of colors, like
colors = new Color[4];

    //Initialize the values of the array
    colors[0] = Color.red;
    colors[1] = Color.blue;
    colors[2] = Color.yellow;
    colors[3] = Color.green

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I finished this task, and employer approved it :)
You can check final version on GitHub:
https://github.com/Wonderio619/QATestTask